Kubernetes Container Get Node's External IP
for a deamonSet I need to know the external IP address of the node the pod/container is running on as an ENV due to an requierment to sent it in the datagram. Unfo. does status.hostIP only contain the local IP of the node.
Thank you in advance.

In environments I've worked in, a best-practice setup has been that nodes are in a private environment and are only accessible via things like LoadBalancer-type Services; a node wouldn't normally have an external IP address.

If you're permitted to access the Metadata Service (it can be concealed with GKE), you can access the VM's external IP: curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip (or some permutation thereof).

In the end I wrote a small python script which then allowed me to connect this information to an external DNS server...
import os
from kubernetes import client, config, watch

# Configure Kubernetes API client
try:
    config.load_kube_config()  # Use kubeconfig file if available
except Exception:
    config.load_incluster_config()  # Use in-cluster config if running inside a cluster

def get_public_ip(node):
    for address in node.status.addresses:
        if address.type == 'ExternalIP':
            return address.address
    return None

def get_all_nodes():
    return v1.list_node().items


If there are external IPs that route to one or more cluster nodes, Kubernetes Services can be exposed on those externalIPs. Traffic that ingresses into the cluster with the external IP (as destination IP), on the Service port, will be routed to one of the Service endpoints. externalIPs are not managed by Kubernetes and are the responsibility of the cluster administrator.
For the application, if you may want to expose a Service onto an external IP address, that is accessible from outside of your cluster. Kubernetes Service types allow you to specify what kind of Service you want. You can use Nodeport type or Load Balancer type or other types to expose your service.
